# SimpleDateFormat Parse Exception Thrown Only On Specific Values

Tags: java, parsing, simpledateformat

I am using the following code to parse date+time strings:

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
    sdf.setLenient(false);
    Date d = sdf.parse(dateStr);
```

This code works perfectly most of the time...
But, I found that it just wouldn't accept the value: "3/28/2014 02:39:59 AM".
Even stranger, when I change the value to any other hour, it works fine.

What am I missing?

(My code is Single threaded, compiled with JDK7, on timezone UTC+2)

Comment: How did you convert the string `3/28/2014 02:39:59 AM` to a `Date` when you faced this issue?

Comment: could you exemplify " when I change the value to any other hour, it works fine"?

Comment: @Blip, for example, "3/28/2014 03:39:59 AM" works... :/

Comment: `3/28/2014 02:39:59 AM` works for me. What's the error? Show stacktrace.

Comment: what you mean by " I found that it just wouldn't accept the value"? does it throw an exception or some error occurs?

Comment: Does it throw a java.text.ParseException? Can you print the result of `Locale.getDefault()` ?

Comment: @Blip Exception occurred in target VM: Unparseable date: "3/28/2014 2:39:59 AM"  java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "3/28/2014 2:39:59 AM"

Comment: @user43250937 My default locale is 'en_US'

Comment: does `3/28/2014 01:39:59 AM` work?

Comment: @LiorAbadi as on my system and that example works, a previous answer that is now deleted pointed out that this could have been a locale issue, that was in fact possible if you had a strange locale (e.g. Locale.JAPANESE).

Comment: Where does that string come from? It's a string that you create or that `3/28/2014 02:39:59 AM` comes from some external component? (e.g. a db, the date is read from a file or something similar)

Comment: @Blip For "3/28/2014 01:39:59 AM" I am getting the Date: '2014-03-28T01:39:59.000+0200'.
For "3/28/2014 03:39:59 AM" I am getting the Date: '2014-03-28T03:39:59.000+0300'.

Does it make any sense to you?

Comment: @user43250937 From excel using Apache POI. In any case, I don't think that's the issue - when trying this with explicit text strings I had the same exception.

Comment: I was asking this because not printable characters in the date string could brake the formatting, agree it can't obviously be that if even with the manual string it doesn't work, weird issue.

Comment: Eventually, I worked around this weird issue by concatenating to each date a string which specify the timezone.

    `SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a z");
    sdf.setLenient(false);
    Date d = sdf.parse(dateStr + " -0700");`
With this fix, all of the dates are now parsed correctly without exceptions.